# iOS Switching Views Function

Tags: ios, animation, uikit

I have an application which has two views on one view controller. One view is above the other.  When someone swipes or presses a button, the view on top moves to the side to display the bottom view. When someone opens a new view and wants to go back to the view controller with the two views, I want to have the view on top to reveal the bottom view automatically. 
This is my code:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end
@implementation ViewController



@synthesize topLayer = _topLayer;
@synthesize layerPosition = _layerPosition;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad]

self.topLayer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1,0);
self.topLayer.layer.shadowOpacity = .9;

self.layerPosition = self.topLayer.frame.origin.x;
}

#define VIEW_HIDDEN 264

-(void) animateLayerToPoint:(CGFloat)x
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = self.topLayer.frame;
                     frame.origin.x = x;
                     self.topLayer.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     self.layerPosition =self.topLayer.frame.origin.x;

                 }];
}

- (IBAction)toggleLayer:(id)sender {


    if (self.layerPosition == VIEW_HIDDEN) {
        [self animateLayerToPoint:0];
    } else {
        [self animateLayerToPoint:VIEW_HIDDEN];
    }



}

- (IBAction)panLayer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)pan {
if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint point  = [pan translationInView:self.topLayer];
    CGRect frame = self.topLayer.frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.layerPosition + point.x;
    if (frame.origin.x < 0 ) frame.origin.x = 0;
    self.topLayer.frame = frame;
}
if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    if (self.topLayer.frame.origin.x <= 160) {
        [self animateLayerToPoint:0];
    } else {
        [self animateLayerToPoint: VIEW_HIDDEN];
    }
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to know, how to have the view load with the top view moved aside to reveal the second view when someone presses the back button on another view to go back to this view.

Comment: if you are using a navigation controller that should already happen

Comment: I am not sure if I am. When I press back on from the other view controller, and the initial view controller loads, the top view is above the bottom view and is not revealing it.

Comment: why aren't you using two UIViewControllers? one for each view? your description is that of reimplementing the UINavigationViewController's functionality. The [UIViewController Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html) can help out a lot.

Comment: What I have is like the facebook app. It slides across to reveal something else

Answer (score 0):

Override `-viewWillAppear` to arrange the views however you want them based on the state of the app. If the user hasn't swiped or whatever, put the first view on top. If they have swiped or whatever, move the view to the side.

`-viewDidLoad` is the right place to perform any setup that needs to happen when the view is first loaded. `-viewWillAppear` is the place to do things that should happen just before the view controller's view is displayed, and it's called every time that happens.

Comment: Could you tell me what to write? Thanks.

Comment: I thought I just did. You seem to know how to move the top view. Presumably, you also know when the user has performed whatever action is necessary to move the view. Seems like the only thing that's left is to have your view controller remember whether the user has already moved the view, so that you can move it again the next time the view is displayed. You may only need a `BOOL` instance variable or property for that.

Comment: I got it working, thanks. Though I am encountering a problem when the app opens up. I dont want the top view to move to the side when the app opens up for the first time

Comment: @ArmanPuri That's why I wrote that you should *arrange the views however you want them based on the state of the app*. The view controller should keep track of whether the user has performed the action necessary to move the view and, if so, move it. If not, don't move it. `if (self.userHasSwiped == YES) { /* move the view*/ }`